# Literature recommendation Integral CV Fluid Mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, flow

I wanted to ask for book or literature in general recommended for control volumes in Fluid Mechanics. Particularly about non inertial and deformable CV which is a topic that basic Fluid Mechanics books tend to explain shallowly.

Comment: handwritten notes about balance equations for continuum mechanics https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/CM/BalanceEquations/povIntegral.html. Light blue for links. Maybe incomplete and messy. Try to have a look around and let me know